# var socket = io.connect('http://yourhostname/');?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I try socket.io again since v.1.0 released.

As the doc,
https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io

---

**Server side:**

```
var server = require('http').Server();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('event', function(data){});
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
});
server.listen(5000);
```

---

**Client side**

`var socket = io.connect('http://yourhostname.com/');`

In development, surely

`var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000/');`

---

It works, but I'm very uncomfortable with hardcoding the hostname(subdomain.domain) in the client code(/index.js).

The index.js is hosted by the http-sever and the socket.io is bundled to the http-server in this configuration.

Is there any smart way not to hardcode the hostname but to code in some relative path?

Thanks.

EDIT:

When I try:

```
var socket = io.connect('./');
```

The connection error:

```
GET http://.:5000/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1401659441615-0 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

is like this, so at least the port number (5000) is obtained properly without hardcoding in the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final answer.

I have totally forgotton that we can obtain the current url/domain in browser.

`window.location.hostname`

So, simply goes:

```
'use strict';
/*global window, require, console, __dirname, $,alert*/

var log = function(msg)
{
    console.log(msg);
};
log('init');

$('document').ready(function()
{
    var io = require('socket.io-client');

    var socket = io.connect(window.location.hostname);
    socket.on('connect', function()
    {
        log('socket connected');
    });

});
```

Comment: window.location.host seems better. It contains the port number.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that Node.js is not a web server. It's a platform. When you specify a relative path, it doesn't know that you mean "relative to the current domain."

What you need to do is send the domain to the client when you send them the webpage (I don't know the specifics of your setup, but perhaps using a template variable?), and send them the `localhost:5000` domain if you're in development, or your real domain if you're in production (alternatively, you can use a library like nconf, but you get the idea).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just posted my own answer. Check it out.

Answer (score -1):

dunno, so far I did as follows:

```
'use strict';
/*global window, require, console, __dirname, $,alert*/

var log = function(msg)
{
    console.log(msg);
};
log('init');

$.getJSON("../config.json", function(data)
{
    var host = data.url;
    var port = data.port;

    $('document').ready(function()
    {
        alert(host + ':' + port);

        var io = require('socket.io-client');

        var socket = io.connect(host);
        socket.on('connect', function()
        {
            log('socket connected');
        });

    });

});
```

It's `browserified` with `socket.io-client`.